# How can I change the death wait to 1 second in COD4: Modern Warfare in free for all games?

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I host a server for me and my friends (Call of Duty 4 : Modern Warfare).  We all enjoy playing hardcore but loath the wait (10 seconds after every death).  I found some commands for the server console for **EVERY GAME MODE EXCEPT FREE FOR ALL!**

Instead, we've just been doing Team Deathmatch but, with that, there doesn't feel like there is enough targets.

Here is the command I used to set the wait time to 1 second in Team Deathmatch:

```
/scr_war_numlives 0
/scr_war_playerrespawndelay 1
/scr_war_waverespawndelay 0
```

Now, does anybody know a possible way/command to make Free For Alls timer only 1 second or remove it completely?

A guess another possible solution would be to change the health that all players have in just normal core to being the amount that a hardcore player has (30?) and then the wait would be the same.

Anyways, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

/scr_dm_playerrespawndelay -1

dm is for free-for-all

Answer (score 0):

/scr_dm_waverespawndelay 1

the dm is for free for all.